# How do I convert this function from MySQL to MySQLi? The MySQLresult

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried pretty much everything I could, so I'm hoping someone will help me out with this.

```
     function user_exists($username) {
        $username = sanitize($username);
        return (mysql_result( mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` ='$username' "), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this function somewhere. Try this:

```
function mysqli_result($res,$row=0,$col=0)
{ 
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res); 
    if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row >=0){
        mysqli_data_seek($res,$row);
        $resrow = (is_numeric($col)) ? mysqli_fetch_row($res) : mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if (isset($resrow[$col])){
            return $resrow[$col];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```